# Android project not build

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
>   Disable offline mode and sync project
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app

Comment: Connect you pc or laptop with internet then try to sync gradle again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that you can try,

1) First check connect with **internet** or not if it is connected then try to sync gradle again.

2) If the **internet** is proper working then Go to,

```
File->Other Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->
Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.
```

[image]